# Unshift function creates additional buttons when clicked via Reactjs -Jquery

Tags: jquery, reactjs

Unshift function creates additional buttons when clicked via Reactjs -Jquery.

I lifted this code from this venerable site **stackoverflow**.

I have three users in an array.
Here am trying allow each user to have his popup box display when his/her corresponding users link button is clicked.

To this effect, I do not currently know how to purely do it with reactjs so I combine it with jquery by adding the code below

```
if ($.inArray(pid, this.state.data) != -1)
     {
      this.state.data.splice($.inArray(pid, this.state.data), 1);
     }
this.state.data.unshift(pid);


                var s = 270 ; // start position
        var j = 260;  //next position

        $.each( this.state.data, function( index, value ) {  
           if(index < 4){
             $('[rel="'+value+'"]').css("right",s);
             $('[rel="'+value+'"]').show();
             s = s+j;            
           }
           else{
             $('[rel="'+value+'"]').hide();
           }
        });
```

And in the **render method**, am having div with rel set to person.id as per code below

```
rel={person.id}
```

**Here is my achievement and issues:**

When I click on each users button,everything works fine and each users corresponding popup box is displayed but the **Unshif()** function in this line of
code below causes an additional click button to be displayed.

```
this.state.data.unshift(pid);
```

This additional click button, I do not know where its coming from.
so instead of having three users button, am having six after click.

I do not know whether if its jquery combination that is causing the issue with reactjs. 
Can someone help me with that.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
/*
const itemToPush = {
    id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16)

}
*/

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      showBox: false,
data: [
        { id: "1", name: "user 1" },
        { id: "2", name: "user 2"},
        { id: "3", name: "user 3"}
      ],
    };

    this.showBox = this.showBox.bind(this);
    this.closeBox = this.closeBox.bind(this);
  }



  componentWillMount() {



}




showBox = (i, pid, name) => {

alert('you opened Box for User ' +pid);

// please uncomment the code below
/*
if ($.inArray(pid, this.state.data) != -1)
     {
      this.state.data.splice($.inArray(pid, this.state.data), 1);
     }
this.state.data.unshift(pid);


                var s = 270 ; // start position
        var j = 260;  //next position

        $.each( this.state.data, function( index, value ) {  
           if(index < 4){
             $('[rel="'+value+'"]').css("right",s);
             $('[rel="'+value+'"]').show();
             s = s+j;            
           }
           else{
             $('[rel="'+value+'"]').hide();
           }
        });

*/      

    //event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showBox: true }, () => {
     document.addEventListener('click', this.closeBox);
    });

  }

  closeBox(event) {

    if (this.dropdownBox.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({ showBox: false }, () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeBox);
      });   

    }
  }
  render() {


var hidden = {
            display: this.state.shownToggle ? "none" : "block"
        }


    return (
      <div>


          <ul  style={{float: "right"}}>
            {this.state.data.map((person, i) => (

              <div className="chat-sidebar" key={i}>

                <button onClick={ () => this.showBox(i, person.id, person.name)}>
                 {person.name} Box</button>




        {this.state.showBox
            ? (



<div rel={person.id} style={{right: '270px',position: 'fixed', bottom:'-5px', width:'250px',background: 'white',borderRadius:'5px 5px 0px 0px'}}>
<div >
<div ref={(element) => {this.dropdownBox = element;}} style={{color: 'white',background: 'black'}}>Close</div>
 </div>
<div> <div style={{background: 'red',height: '100px'}}>Content will be here............<div ref={(element) => {this.dropdownBox = element;}} style={{color: 'blue'}}>Close</div></div>
</div>           
</div>
            ): (
              null
            )}



</div>

            ))}
          </ul>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**An Updates according to Sir Arun Krish....**

Sir Arun Krish, I have updated the code below to reflect your solution but am still having the same issue of additional three pop button after click.

Here is what that happens. Initially, the app has three buttons representing three users. when I click on each button, the users popup box will be displayed but an additonal empty button will be showed for each.

Please can you help me further.Please Sir can you replace that jquery code with pure reactjs. Thanks  Below is the screenshoot

[image: see screenshot]
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    import { render } from "react-dom";
    import axios from 'axios';
    //import './style_chat.css';

```
const itemToPush = {
    id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 16)

}


class ChatReact extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      showBox: false,
data: [
        { id: "1", name: "user 1" },
        { id: "2", name: "user 2"},
        { id: "3", name: "user 3"}
      ],
    };

    this.showBox = this.showBox.bind(this);
    this.closeBox = this.closeBox.bind(this);
  }
 componentWillMount() { 
}




showBox = (i, pid, name) => {
alert('you opened Box for User ..... ' +pid);

const dataSet = this.state.data;
  if ($.inArray(pid, dataSet) != -1)
   {
    dataSet.splice($.inArray(pid, this.state.data), 1);
    }
    dataSet.unshift(pid);
    var s = 270 ; // start position
    var j = 260;  //next position

    $.each( dataSet, function( index, value ) {  
       if(index < 4){
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').css("right",s);
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').show();

         s = s+j;   

       }
       else{
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').hide();
       }
    });

    //event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showBox: true }, () => {

     document.addEventListener('click', this.closeBox);
    });

  }

  closeBox(event) {

    if (this.dropdownBox.contains(event.target)) {
      this.setState({ showBox: false }, () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeBox);
      });   

    }
  }
  render() {


var hidden = {
            display: this.state.shownToggle ? "none" : "block"
        }


    return (
      <div>


          <ul  style={{float: "right"}}>
            {this.state.data.map((person, i) => (

              <div className="chat-sidebar" key={i}>

                <button onClick={ () => this.showBox(i, person.id, person.name)}>
                 {person.name} Box</button>




        {this.state.showBox
            ? (



<div rel={person.id} className="msg_box" style={{right: '270px',position: 'fixed', bottom:'-5px', width:'250px',background: 'white',borderRadius:'5px 5px 0px 0px'}}>
<div >
<div ref={(element) => {this.dropdownBox = element;}} style={{color: 'white',background: 'black'}}>Close</div>
 </div>
<div> <div style={{background: 'red',height: '100px'}}>Content will be here............<div ref={(element) => {this.dropdownBox = element;}} style={{color: 'blue'}}>Close</div></div>
</div>           
</div>
            ): (
              null
            )}



</div>

            ))}
          </ul>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So, a few things. First, NEVER modify `this.state` directly (such as using `unshift`). You should ALWAYS be using `this.setState` when you want to modify React state. Second, there is almost never a good reason to mix React and jQuery. jQuery relies on direct DOM manipulation (such as your `$('[rel="'+value+'"]').show();`) which can and will cause React to have problems.

Comment: As an aside, the one place it's ok to modify `state` directly is in a constructor, because `setState` is probably (always?) not yet defined, and there is nothing that needs re-rendering, since you haven't rendered the component at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assigb the state to a variable, thereby avoiding the direct manipulation of state

```
  const dataSet = this.state.data;
  if ($.inArray(pid, dataSet) != -1)
   {
    dataSet.splice($.inArray(pid, this.state.data), 1);
    }
    dataSet.unshift(pid);
      var s = 270 ; // start position
    var j = 260;  //next position

    $.each( dataSet, function( index, value ) {  
       if(index < 4){
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').css("right",s);
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').show();
         s = s+j;            
       }
       else{
         $('[rel="'+value+'"]').hide();
       }
    });
//event.preventDefault();

this.setState({ showBox: true }, () => {
 document.addEventListener('click', this.closeBox);
});
```

}

Comment: Sir Arun Krish, thanks for your contributions so far. I have implemented your solution but am still having the same issue of three empty button coming up after click. I have added the screenshot of what am having showing those three additional empty button that I do not know where its coming from. Please Sir can you see the  Updates Sections according to Sir Arun Krish.... on my post for details. Between Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sir Arun. Your solution really help me